# Ran Update Query Without Where Clause

Tags: mysql

Ran update query update:

```
update "payment_advice_headers set gl_date = created_at;
```

using sequal pro - Query was running, I clicked on stop button, but the query was still running, I opened up the DB in new tab, and killed the process which was running, and the query stopped - Does it mean the query updated the entities till I stopped the process, or it did not updated the data at all?

It's a production environment and I need to take actions ASAP to revert if the query has updated some entities.

Comment: You should look at your data instead of asking us if it really changed anything...

Comment: Also, if that is the exact query you ran, it probably did nothing because of the quotation mark at the beginning

Comment: Also, if you are ever writing an update or delete directly on a production server, you should write the WHERE before writing anything else. I typically write them as a select first to make sure I'm going to update/delete the correct rows.